Adding dSYM to XCFramwork
I have been using an XCFramework for some time without issues. However, after upgrading to Xcode 16, I encountered the following warning when trying to upload to the App Store:

Upload Symbols Failed
The archive did not include a dSYM for the MYFramwork.framework with the UUIDs [602AD530-2D61-3192-90DD-EB050F0C6751]. Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for MYFramwork.framework with the expected UUIDs.

I tried adding the dSYM file to my XCFramework, but doing so significantly increased the framework size.
Do I really need to include the dSYM? If so, is there a way to reduce its size?
Here is my build script:
This is my build code:
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework "../$IOS_ARCHIVE_PATH/Products/Library/Frameworks/$POD_NAME.framework" \
-debug-symbols "$PWD/../$IOS_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/$POD_NAME.framework.dSYM" \
-framework "../$IOS_SIM_ARCHIVE_PATH/Products/Library/Frameworks/$POD_NAME.framework" \
-debug-symbols "$PWD/../$IOS_SIM_ARCHIVE_PATH/dSYMs/$POD_NAME.framework.dSYM" \
-output $OUTPUT_FRAMEWORK_PATH


The size of the XCFramework has no direct correlation to a size of the app when someone uses your xcframework, or the size of the app as it downloads to an end user. So why do you care that size with dSYMs is bigger?

The error you see on Xcode 16 uploads, if your XCFramework is static and working fine on Xcode 15, is likely an Xcode 16 bug that is actively documented here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/761589
